# If $f_n(x)$ is continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$ converging uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove the question in the title and believe that I have arrived at a $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ argument. Could anyone take a look at it and provide any comments or insight, it seems an important theorem.

Suppose that $x \in [a,b]$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then since $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly to $f$, $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n\geq N$

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, $\forall x \in [a, b], \forall n \geq N$. Also, since $f_N(x)$ is continuous 
$\exists \delta > 0$ so that if $y \in [a,b]$ and $|x-y| < \delta$

then $|f_N(y) - f_N(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Then we have for $y \in [a,b]$ and $|x-y| < \delta$ that

$ |f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f_N(x) - f(y) + f_N(y) + f_N(x) - f_N(y)|$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \leq |f_N(x) -f(x)| + |f_N(y) - f(y)| + |f_N(x) + f_N(y)|$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon $

Comment: That is the good ole $\epsilon /3$ proof for it. Good job.

Comment: Yes you are right. The proof involving triangle inequality is a standard trick in analysis.

Comment: I think you dropped a quantifier somewhere, because what you wrote doesn't give $|f_N(y) - f(y)| \leq \epsilon/3$.

Comment: He should've put $\forall n \geq N$ and $\forall x \in [a,b]$. But that's being pedantic, he has uniform convergence it is implied.

Comment: Sorry, I just use the fact that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}, \forall n \geq N$ and certainly this holds for $n = N$ but I should have clarified.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your proof is correct. As for the importance of it as a theorem, it is a nice particular case of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Federico How is it a particular case of the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @AOrtiz   Well, maybe more than "a particular case" I should have said "an immediate consequence". The collection $\{|f_n|\}$ is uniformly bounded, so you can take a constant that dominates them all, that will be integrable since the domain has finite measure.